# Extracting URL parameters in cakephp with URL that ends with xml

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, url-parameters

I would like to pass URL parameters in cakephp with URL that ends with xml like below;

```
http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info?page=1.xml
```

The controller function looks like this;

```
public function api_get_info()
{
    if($this->RequestHandler->responseType() == 'xml')
    {
        //Problem is that the code never executes inside this if statement
        //Controller action

    }
}
```

The problem is that the code never executes inside the if statement `if($this->RequestHandler->responseType() == 'xml')`. However, if the URL becomes `http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info.xml`, then the code will execute inside the if statement. Unfortunately, this is not what I want because the URL parameters cannot be sent.

How can I pass URL parameters in cakephp with URL that ends with xml? I am using cakephp 2.5.1

Thank you.

Comment: Why not using `http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info.xml?page=1` etc? Either way you should have the extension directly inside the URL prio to starting query strings.

Comment: The code works now!! Thanks!!

Comment: @mark: if you put your comment as answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is flawed.

```
http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info.xml
```

actually IS the correct format.

```
http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info?page=1.xml
```

is not (if you want query strings to work while using xml extension routing).

If you want to append query strings, always do that after the URL itself, e.g.

```
http://localhost/cp251/controller/api_get_info.xml?page=xxx&more=stuff
```